# kubuntu 16.10 can not establish connection to wlan router

Tags: drivers, wireless, kubuntu, broadcom, 16.10

I crashed my last kubuntu installation (updated 14.04) and installed a new kubuntu 16.10 from a Live USB stick.
The installation went well, but then the internet connection does not work.
normaly I do a right-click on the wlan-icon in the systray, select my wlan and enter my password. then I could use the internet.

Not after this installation. I did the same but instead of a connection I only get the message "disconnected from 'mySSID'" after some time. Meanwhile I had to enter my password multiple times.

Then I remove the entry from the connection-editor (Verbindungseditor), insert the connection anew and it works. but only sometimes. after the next boot (or standby) the connection is not available any more.

more strange: sometimes the wlan connection works, but only very slowly. at this times my notebook is not visible in the list of connections of my router (so I just use the connection to access the service menu of the router)

As I have an older Lenovo B590 I found some hints to enable/disable any b43 drivers, but playing around does not result in a stable wlan (fast and reliable after reboot)

I also have an old working 14.04 (not updated) on HD from which I can boot and have a stable and reliable wlan connection.

more info:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ee37299201ed2d3d14f992cf82a60626

Comment: You're using the worst wireless encryption settings that are know to work poorly with some devices in Linux. Just change it, at the router, to WPA2-AES only, not any WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP (your current settings).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: @CelticWarrior: there is no possible selection for WPA2/AES. only options are: `Verschlüsselungsmethode:   WPA/WPA2    Nur WPA2    Nur WPA    WEP    Ausgeschaltet   (WPA/WPA2)`. Maybe I have not found that option (it's an easybox 803 router), so any hints are welcome.

Comment: That is where you select WPA2 only. Somewhere else it should be possible to select the algorithm. If it supports TKIP only (unlikely)  then it's time for Vodafone to replace it. Easybox 803 is around 10 years old.